# How to add UITableView to UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I am new to iOS development and trying to develop a sample phone book application. Each contact carries (Name, Image, Email and other stuff).
Through storyboard, I tried creating `UITableViewController` with one prototype cell. Now in the cell I tried to add one `UITableView` (3 rows) to hold contact information, but not working.

Is this the right way? Using StackView (Vertically) will fail in iOS 8, so I am trying to use tables.

Comment: Adding UITableView into your UITableViewCell is not good approach since user of your app may end up really confused. 

I advice you to read Apple Human Interface Guidelines - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/

Comment: Thank you, what is the solution for this problem? How can i achieve my requirement, could you explain.

Comment: You can use a custom table view cell and add all the labels and image to that and then loaded in your uitablviewcontroller.  Check out this tutorial http://www.makemegeek.com/custom-uitableviewcell-example-ios/